# DB2 restore incremental backup tablespace to different db

Tags: db2

I have server1 and server2 in my environment, both have db2 v11.1 installed.

I have already done an online tablespaces (TS1, TS2, TS3) incremental backup of my database GS_DB and obtained the below 3 images.

```
Image1 at timestamp1: 20190215162151     (full online backup of TS1,TS2,TS3)
Image2 at timestamp2: 20190215162254     (incremental online backup of TS1,TS2,TS3)
Image3 at timestamp3: 20190215162725     (incremental online backup of TS1,TS2,TS3)
```

In server1, suppose I want to restore my db to image2 (20190215162254), I can do:

```
db2ckrst -d GS_DB -t 20190215162254 -r tablespace
Suggested restore order of images using timestamp 20190215162254 for database gs_db.
====================================================================
restore db gs_db tablespace ( TS1, TS2, TS3 ) incremental taken at 20190215162254
restore db gs_db incremental taken at 20190215162151
restore db gs_db incremental taken at 20190215162254
====================================================================
```

If I follow the order and restore to the existing GS_DB in server1, it is working fine.

Now I transferred 3 images to server2 and created an empty database GS_DB in server2, then try to use the above command to restore tablespaces TS1,TS2,TS3 to GS_DB in server2:

```
db2 restore db gs_db2 tablespace ( TS1, TS2, TS3 ) incremental taken at 20190215162254
SQL2560N  The table space restore operation failed because the target database is not identical to the source database.
```

Already stuck at the first command, does it mean we cannot restore tablespace backup image across two different db? Any way I can do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Every database has an unique internal identifier called `Seed`. You can't create another database with the same `Seed` as the existing one, even you create it with the same name. These databases are different from the DB2's point of view.
Citation from the [Restoring to an existing database](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006250.html) article:

> The database manager assigns the seed when you create the database.
>   Db2® always uses the seed from the backup image.
>   **You can restore a table space into an existing database only if the table space exists and if the table spaces are the same, meaning that you did not drop
>   the table space and then re-create it between the backup and the
>   restore operations**.
>   **The database on disk and in the backup image must
>   be the same**.

So, yes, you are not able to restore tablespace backup image across two different db in the way you try.
Read about the [Database schema transporting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0057037.html) feature.